# run node.js by pm2,but often restart:exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am trying to run node.js on my system but running into this problem:

```
2016-06-01 20:46:28: App [app] with id [13] and pid [12633], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:28: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:13
2016-06-01 20:46:28: App name:app id:13 online
2016-06-01 20:46:28: App name:app id:4 disconnected
2016-06-01 20:46:28: App [app] with id [4] and pid [47284], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:28: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:4
2016-06-01 20:46:29: App name:app id:4 online
2016-06-01 20:46:44: App name:app id:3 disconnected
2016-06-01 20:46:44: App [app] with id [3] and pid [42456], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:44: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:3
2016-06-01 20:46:44: App name:app id:3 online
2016-06-01 20:46:45: App name:app id:2 disconnected
2016-06-01 20:46:45: App [app] with id [2] and pid [47045], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:45: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:2
2016-06-01 20:46:45: App name:app id:2 online
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App name:app id:6 disconnected
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App [app] with id [6] and pid [47326], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:49: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:6
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App name:app id:6 online
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App name:app id:10 disconnected
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App [app] with id [10] and pid [47291], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2016-06-01 20:46:49: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:10
2016-06-01 20:46:49: App name:app id:10 online
2016-06-01 20:48:33: App name:app id:2 disconnected
```

I run node.js using pm2, but it often restarts because of the following: `exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]`. Why is this?

Some additional information:

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       40G  9.8G   28G  27% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  380K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

~$ free -m
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16035       8177       7857          0        174       3672
-/+ buffers/cache:       4331      11704
Swap:            0          0          0

~$ node -v
v5.1.1

~$ npm -v
3.3.12
```

Comment: Does your code run properly without pm2?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue where pm2 was restarting every second and uptime was 0s. I found a work around:

1. `pm2 start bin/www -i 0` // this will start a cluster and the main app
2. `pm2 stop 0` // this will allow the cluster to keep running

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error message when running pm2 with a 3rd-party utility:

```
PM2 | App [Utility:2] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

PM2 just kept restarting the utility.

And I tried running the utility without pm2, it did not actually exit. I was wondering why pm2 decided to restart the utility. (No answer yet, though from the log, it's due to SIGINT)

We don't want the utility to keep restarting.

#### Solution / Workaround

What we found is, if we use pm2 to **run the utility in cluster mode** instead of fork mode(see `exec_mode: 'cluster_mode'` below), the utility works without keeping restarting.

pm2.utility.config.js

```
const pm2Config = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Utility',
      script: './3rd/utility.js',
      exec_mode: 'cluster_mode',
      instances: 1,
    },
  ],
}

module.exports = pm2Config
```

Then run pm2:

```
pm2 start pm2.utility.config.js
```

**Note**: my pm2 is of version 3.4.0.

Comment: adding cluster worked for me, i think some times we may need to run pm2 delete all once before starting pm2

Answer (score 1):

please check your

> app.listen(portid,"private_ip");

line in my case this is commented and when I uncommented its work

Comment: In which file is this line? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If your are running pm2 in cluster mode and trying to create instances more than 1 and getting the error you reported, check how many cpu core your machine has. Because if your cpu has got only one core and you are trying to run pm2 with more then one instance you will get error however forking mode will not give you error.

Comment: you can check cpu core in ubuntu with this command :  grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 0):

Use the js file name as value of script key in ecosystem.config.js , `script : "index.js"` (correct) rather than `script : "node index.js"` (wrong) when using pm2 in cluster mode.

Refer this comment at [github](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4632#issuecomment-1203779272)