# Running Gatsby JS with PM2

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, gatsby, pm2

This post has been updated with new information based on debugging

I am attempting to do a deploy with pm2 for a GatsbyJS site on EC2. I previously was able to get Gatsby to run manually on ec2 with pm2, but not with a deploy.

Here is my `ecosystem.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [{
      name: 'wispyCo',
      script: 'npm',
      args : 'start',
      watch: '.',
      env:{
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        MY_SANITY_TOKEN : "fdsa",
        SANITY_TOKEN_WRITE : "fdsaf",
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL : "fds"
      }
    },
  ],

    deploy : {
      production : {
        user : 'ubuntu',
        host : 'ec2-54-226-83-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        ref  : 'origin/development',
        repo : 'git@github.com:fdsafa',
        path : '/home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy',
        'pre-deploy-local': '',
        'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
        'pre-setup': '',
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is my scripts for package.json for Gatsby

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 --port 8000",
    "start": "run-p start:**",
    "start:app": "npm run develop",
    "start:lambda": "netlify-lambda serve src/lambda",
    "build": "gatsby build && netlify-lambda build src/lambda",
    "build:app": "gatsby build",
    "build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/lambda"
  }
```

What's happening is pm2 just keeps reloading which looks something like this.

```
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:35: PM2 log: pid=31900 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:35: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:35: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] online
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:37: PM2 log: Change detected on path lambda/hello.js for app wispyCo - restarting
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:37: PM2 log: Stopping app:wispyCo id:0
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:37: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:38: PM2 log: pid=32016 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:38: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:38: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] online
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: Change detected on path lambda/hello.js for app wispyCo - restarting
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: Stopping app:wispyCo id:0
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: pid=32132 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-05-07T13:29:40: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] online

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/wispyCo-error.log last 15 lines:
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/wispyCo-out.log last 15 lines:
0|wispyCo  | > run-p start:**
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:app /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > npm run develop
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:lambda /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > netlify-lambda serve src/lambda
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
0|wispyCo  | 
0|wispyCo  | netlify-lambda: Starting server

PM2      | Change detected on path lambda/hello.js for app wispyCo - restarting
PM2      | Stopping app:wispyCo id:0
0|wispyCo  | Hash: d0c09734a446097dbcc4
0|wispyCo  | Version: webpack 4.41.5
0|wispyCo  | Time: 1141ms
0|wispyCo  | Built at: 05/07/2020 1:29:43 PM
0|wispyCo  |    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
0|wispyCo  | hello.js  131 KiB       0  [emitted]  hello
0|wispyCo  | slack.js  277 KiB       1  [emitted]  slack
0|wispyCo  | Entrypoint hello = hello.js
0|wispyCo  | Entrypoint slack = slack.js
0|wispyCo  |   [0] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB {0} [built]
0|wispyCo  |   [2] external "stream" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |   [3] external "url" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |   [5] external "http" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |   [8] external "https" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [14] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [15] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/observable/operators/filter.js 66 bytes {0} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [16] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/observable/operators/map.js 57 bytes {0} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [18] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 2.93 KiB {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [19] external "path" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [23] external "querystring" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [58] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js 7.93 KiB {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [59] ./hello.js 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
0|wispyCo  |  [60] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/sanityClient.js 3.43 KiB {0} [built]
0|wispyCo  | [155] ./slack.js 1000 bytes {1} [built]
0|wispyCo  |     + 165 hidden modules
0|wispyCo  | WARNING in /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
0|wispyCo  | Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
0|wispyCo  |  @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/encoding/lib/encoding.js
0|wispyCo  |  @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/body.js
0|wispyCo  |  @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js
0|wispyCo  |  @ ./slack.js
PM2        | App [wispyCo:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | pid=32248 msg=process killed
PM2        | App [wispyCo:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | App [wispyCo:0] online
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > run-p start:**
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:lambda /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > netlify-lambda serve src/lambda
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:app /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > npm run develop
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
0|wispyCo  | > gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
0|wispyCo  | netlify-lambda: Starting server
```

The pm2.log looks like the following

```
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: Change detected on path lambda/hello.js for app wispyCo - restarting
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: Stopping app:wispyCo id:0
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: pid=4137 msg=process killed
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-05-07T13:31:26: PM2 log: App [wispyCo:0] online
```

The is no error.log but the is a out.log which looks like the following which is just pm2 restarting again

```
> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
> run-p start:**


> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:lambda /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
> netlify-lambda serve src/lambda


> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start:app /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
> npm run develop


> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
> gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

netlify-lambda: Starting server
Hash: d0c09734a446097dbcc4
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 1117ms
Built at: 05/07/2020 1:35:58 PM
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
hello.js  131 KiB       0  [emitted]  hello
slack.js  277 KiB       1  [emitted]  slack
Entrypoint hello = hello.js
Entrypoint slack = slack.js
  [0] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB {0} [built]
  [2] external "stream" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [3] external "url" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [5] external "http" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [8] external "https" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [14] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [15] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/observable/operators/filter.js 66 bytes {0} [built]
 [16] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/observable/operators/map.js 57 bytes {0} [built]
 [18] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 2.93 KiB {0} {1} [built]
 [19] external "path" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [23] external "querystring" 42 bytes {0} {1} [built]
 [58] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js 7.93 KiB {1} [built]
 [59] ./hello.js 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
 [60] /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/sanityClient.js 3.43 KiB {0} [built]
[155] ./slack.js 1000 bytes {1} [built]
    + 165 hidden modules

WARNING in /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/encoding/lib/encoding.js
 @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/body.js
 @ /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js
 @ ./slack.js
Lambda server is listening on 9000

> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy/source
> run-p start:**
```

Comment: The error is coming from the `worker-farm`, which is used for parallelization by `terser-webpack-plugin`, which is used by webpack for minification. Your code has nothing to do with it; it works when using `npm start` because webpack doesn't call upon `terser-webpack-plugin` in development mode. Have you run `npm i` or `npm install` in the directory `/home/ubuntu/wispy-deploy/source`?

Comment: Well, you could always manually add `prr` to `package.json` and see if it works. That seems to be a missing dependency. If that doesn't work, for sure it's an issue with your config. Otherwise, you'll have to do some debugging on why `npm` isn't detecting the `prr` dependency.

Comment: I deleted some of my comments, because they were confusing with my updated debugging above. Basically now pm2 just wont stop restarting and is giving me this error `App [wispyCo:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]`

Comment: That means somehow, the app is being interrupted (i.e. SIGINT, which means signal interrupt) but it's exiting with success (exit code is 0).  This question seems to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612081/run-node-js-by-pm2-but-often-restartexited-with-code-0-via-signal-sigint

Comment: I think I tried both the answers there, but I will give it another shot and report back becasue there could be other factors.

Comment: Still stuck here. Cluster mode doesn't make a difference and I can't use the option to run pm2 start and then /var/www because I am using a deploy script with npm start

Comment: Not sure why you're facing this bug in that case, I'll try to replicate and report back with a solution if I find one.

Comment: ok thanks much appreciated

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this error, sorry. Maybe file an issue on the GitHub repo or try setting the mode to cluster?

Comment: Yeah I tried cluster mode, I will file a issue on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was the following I removed cluster mode, changed watch to false and change the nod env to development in two places

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "wispyCo",
      script: "npm",
      args: "start",
      watch: false,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
        SANITY_TOKEN:
          "fdsf",
        SENDGRID_API_KEY:
          "fsdafs",
        SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL: "fdsfa.org",
      },
    },
  ],

  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "ubuntu",
      host: "fdsaf.amazonaws.com",
      ref: "origin/development",
      repo: "git@github.com:fdsfa.git",
      path: "/home/ubuntu/wispyDeploy",
      "pre-deploy-local": "",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env development && npm install -g gatsby-cli",
      "pre-setup": "",
    },
  },
}
```